# Looking for multilclass classifier that can handle repeated measures

Tags: classification, mixed-model, multi-class

I am looking for a multiclass classifier that can handle repeated measures. Specifically, each of my subjects appears multiple times with the same number of n classes. Now I would like to fit a classifier to this dataset to get an intuition for the feature-label relationship (that is, which features are the most associated with which classes?). Is there a multiclass classifier that can take this into account?

**EDIT:**

My problem is a multi-class problem, not a multi-label problem. I did not know that 'multilabel' and 'multiclass' describe different problems, so I changed the wording.

[image]

Comment: All your data points have the same labels? I can see both subj_id 1 and 2 having the labels 1, 2 and 3. Or I’m missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I am interested in the feature label relationship while accounting for possible within-subject correlations.

Comment: If every point has the same class labels [1, 2, 3], this is not a multi label classification problem. For a feature f, every value it can take produces a class label l. In other words, the class label is not an RV. So I don’t know if a correlation can even be computed.

Comment: Imagine training the classifier only using the features and the y label and further imagine you wouldn't know the subject id. Then someone comes and gives you this additional information. Then I guess one could argue that feature sets within each subjects are more similar to each other than they are between subjects? In other words, that there is a nested structure in the feature set?

Comment: Do all your subjects have the same labels in the same order? e.g. subject_1_labels = [1, 2, 3], then subject_2_labels = [1, 2, 3], subject_n_labels = [1, 2, 3]. Then I don't think there will be any predictive method informative here since the labels are all the same across subject and also have the same ordering as well.

Comment: I don't understand why the ordering of the labels is important? I could also shuffle the rows randomly as long as I don't break the relationship of features and labels (or in other words, as long as I simultaneously shuffle the feature matrix in the same way)

Comment: I might have found a classifier that can handle my problem: It's called mixed multinomial logistic regression (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489140/difference-between-multinomial-logistic-regression-and-mixed-effects-models)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a complete answer but as a first step I would just fit a decision tree and then plot the feature importance to get a better understanding regarding the relationship between $X$ and $Y$. For more info regarding weather your case is a multi-label or a multi-task setting you can look [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) and decide accordingly as to how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I mistakenly used the term 'multilabel' instead of 'multiclass'. Made an edit to my question.